# why laravel task schedular running commands twice after upgrade to laravel 9?

Tags: laravel, cron, laravel-8, laravel-9

Since we have upgraded our laravel project from laravel 8 to laravel 9. we are facing issue that all the commands and jobs mentioned in kernel.php are running twice because of which the system is creating duplicate entries in DB. we didn't make any changes to the code.

We also upgraded the ubuntu version from 16 to 20.

I checked the cron file by this command `crontab -e` but there is a written command only once. maybe on the server from somewhere else ubuntu running one more command as well.

`Kernel.php`

```
 protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {

        //POD STATS update job
        $schedule->job(new PodStatsJob)->everyTenMinutes();
        //Consignment table backup job

      

        #Pickup Email Reminder
        $pickup_reminder_time = substr(getSingleOrganisationSetting("pickup_reminder_time"), 0, 5) ?? '07:00';
      

      
        // $schedule->command('conveyor:indexing')->dailyAt($conveyor_consignment_indexing);

        
    }
```

when I check with this command `ps aux | grep "artisan schedule:run"`

I get this

```
root     1331614  0.0  0.0   2616   528 ?        Ss   15:00   0:00 /bin/sh -c cd /var/www/html/coldxlogistics && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
root     1331616  0.0  0.9 216924 77220 ?        S    15:00   0:03 php artisan schedule:run
root     1345894  0.0  0.0   2616   592 ?        Ss   17:39   0:00 /bin/sh -c cd /var/www/html/coldxlogistics && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
ubuntu   1345895  0.0  0.0   2616   600 ?        Ss   17:39   0:00 /bin/sh -c cd /var/www/html/coldxlogistics && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
root     1345896 27.0  0.9 216924 79020 ?        S    17:39   0:00 php artisan schedule:run
ubuntu   1345897 28.0  0.9 216924 78944 ?        S    17:39   0:00 php artisan schedule:run
ubuntu   1345911  0.0  0.0   8484  2428 pts/0    S+   17:39   0:00 grep --color=auto artisan schedule:run
```

Comment: Maybe are you running schedule:work and schedule:run together?

Comment: @FrancescoGallo I updated question please have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that two users **root** and **ubuntu** are running the same command `php artisan schedule:run`:

```
root     1345896 27.0  0.9 216924 79020 ?        S    17:39   0:00 php artisan schedule:run
ubuntu   1345897 28.0  0.9 216924 78944 ?        S    17:39   0:00 php artisan schedule:run
```

You maybe need to run the service on only one user.